# Nginx Single Sign On - auth_request module

Tags: nginx, auth-request

The flow that I wish to implement

```
         Requests with                                                      
Client +------------------------>Nginx                                      
         Access token set          +                                        
                                   |                                        
                                   +------>auth_request to microservice     
                                           which **somehow** returns user id
                                             +                              
                                             |                              
                                             |                              
                                             |                              
         Request forwarded to       <--------+                              
         main microservice which                                            
         can access user id                                                 
         and has nothing to do with                                         
         access token
```

How do I go about executing such an microservice architecture? The main thing is I want to pass data from one microservice to another microservice while not giving access to second microservice if

Comment: **somehow** could be http header, which could be used in `auth_request_set` directive

Comment: @AlexeyTen If you can pls elaborate and give a sample I would be grateful. Do you mean setting header in auth microservice? **Then how to access it in `auth_request_set` ?**

Comment: Have you read documentation? `auth_request_set $userid $upstream_http_userid;` assuming, your microservice sets header `userid`

Comment: Oh okay and then `proxy_set_header userid $userid;`. Thanks for the help. If you wish you can copy and paste your comments as answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement a few days ago for a cluster. I solved it creating an [authentication server](https://github.com/clems4ever/two-factor-auth-server) compatible with the **nginx auth_request** module. It authenticates against my LDAP and enforces security with 2-factor verification thanks to TOTP and Google Authenticator app for example.